# Windows Automatically Update Host File for Local Machine IP Address

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation

I develop multiple applications and host them on my work laptop for local debugging.  In order to access these sites I input a url that the host file redirects to the laptop's IP address.

My question is how do I automatically update my hosts file to map those url's to the machine's current IP address.

This would be incredibly helpful, as I dock the machine at my desk and receive one IP address, and then walk to a meeting connect to wifi and receive another IP address.  It would be great if I never had to worry about this again.

Comment: Not sure I follow, if you use `your.domain.com 127.0.0.1` then the host name will always be local

Comment: Please read carefully ==> [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
==> [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
==> [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
===> [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: If you are open to a C# solution, I can probably help you. Though as it stands now, your question is likely to get closed before I have the opportunity to offer you an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration.  The reason for not using the localhost entry is to host applications that will be on separate domains and and that have various SSL certifications.

Answer (score 0):

In the grand scheme of things... All you need to do is write a structured text file in a protected area. To do so `automatically` with `no user interaction` you first need the user to grand your application permission to do so. Once you are given access, it's business as usual.

Below is a slightly modified copy/paste of an application I wrote to change a Host file. As-is, it does not do exactly what YOU want to do but, everything is there for you to tailor it accordingly. As-is, this is a command line tool.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace ModifyHostFile
{
    class Program
    {
        const string HostFileLocation = @"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts";
        const string HostFileTmpLocation = @"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts_tmp";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WelcomeUser();

            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Must supply action switch [A]dd, or [R]emove entries");
                args = new string[1];
                args.SetValue(Console.ReadLine(), 0);
            }

            switch (args[0].ToUpper())
            {
                case "A":
                    Console.WriteLine("Ok, this will ADD entries in your HOST file.");
                    AddEntriesToHostFile();
                    break;
                case "R":
                    Console.WriteLine("Ok, this will REMOVE entries from your HOST file.");
                    RemoveOurEntriesFromHostFile();
                    break;
                case "EXIT":
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Action switch not recognized.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to quit");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to quit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }

        private static void WelcomeUser()
        {
            int padCount = 119;
            char padChar = '#';
            List<string> messageLines = new List<string>();
            messageLines.Add("#");
            messageLines.Add("Welcome to \"Modify Host File\"");
            messageLines.Add("This tool can execute 2 actions.");
            messageLines.Add("It can add specific entries to your Host file.");
            messageLines.Add("It can remove specific entries from your host file.");
            messageLines.Add("Entries are removed so you can get your original file back.");
            messageLines.Add("#");

            messageLines = messageLines.Select(p => p.PadForConsole(padChar, padCount)).ToList();

            foreach (string item in messageLines)
            {
                ConsoleColor originalColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine(item);
                Console.ForegroundColor = originalColor;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        public static void RemoveOurEntriesFromHostFile()
        {
            HostEntriesToadd entries = new ModifyHostFile.HostEntriesToadd();
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(HostFileLocation))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(HostFileTmpLocation, false))
                    {
                        string currentLine = string.Empty;
                        while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            if (entries.Contains(currentLine))
                            {
                                //don't write the line
                                Console.WriteLine("Removed " + currentLine + " from host file");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //write the line
                                sw.WriteLine(currentLine);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                ReplaceTheFiles(HostFileTmpLocation, HostFileLocation);
            }
            catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                WarnForElevatedPermissions();
            }

        }

        public static void AddEntriesToHostFile()
        {
            HostEntriesToadd entries = new ModifyHostFile.HostEntriesToadd();
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(HostFileTmpLocation, false))
                {
                    sw.Write(File.ReadAllText(HostFileLocation));
                    foreach (string item in entries)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(item);
                        Console.WriteLine("Added " + item + " from host file");
                    }
                }
                ReplaceTheFiles(HostFileTmpLocation, HostFileLocation);
            }
            catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                WarnForElevatedPermissions();
            }

        }

        private static void WarnForElevatedPermissions()
        {
            ConsoleColor originalColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Access Violation Exception");
            if (!IsAdministrator())
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("IsAdministrator: False");
                Console.ForegroundColor = originalColor;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("IsAdministrator: True");
                Console.ForegroundColor = originalColor;
            }
            Console.ForegroundColor = originalColor;
            Console.WriteLine("This tool will re-write your System's host file.");
            Console.WriteLine("Because your System's host file resides in a protected area on your computer");
            Console.WriteLine("this tool MUST run with elevated permissions, aka run as administrator.");

            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        public static bool ReplaceTheFiles(string FileToReplaceWith, string FileToReplace)
        {
            try
            {
                File.Copy(FileToReplaceWith, FileToReplace, true);//overwrite the old file
                File.Delete(FileToReplaceWith);//delete the tmp file
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public static bool IsAdministrator()
        {
            return (new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()))
                    .IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
        }

    }



    public class HostEntriesToadd : List<string>
    {
        public HostEntriesToadd()
        {
            this.Add("127.0.0.1 www.somesite.com");
            this.Add("127.0.0.1 someothersite.com");
            this.Add("127.0.0.1 blahblahblah.com");
            this.Add("127.0.0.1 damnthatdamn.com");
            this.Add("127.0.0.1 whateveryouwant.com");
        }
    }

    public static class StringHelpers
    {
        public static string PadForConsole(this string Text, char PadWith, int TotalLineLength)
        {
            List<string> texts = new List<string>();
            texts.Add(Text);
            if (texts[0].Length >= TotalLineLength - 2)
            {
                texts.Add(string.Empty);
                for (int i = 0; i < texts[0].Length; i++)
                {
                    if (texts.Last().Length < TotalLineLength - 2)
                    {
                        texts[texts.Count - 1] = texts[texts.Count - 1] + texts[0][i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        texts.Add(texts[0][i].ToString());
                    }
                }
                texts.RemoveAt(0);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < texts.Count; i++)
            {
                string currentLine = texts[i].ToString();
                int leftPadCount = ((TotalLineLength - currentLine.Length) / 2);
                string leftPadString = new string(PadWith, leftPadCount);
                //int rightPadCount = (TotalLineLength - currentLine.Length) / 2;
                int rightPadCount = (TotalLineLength - currentLine.Length - leftPadCount);
                string rightPadString = new string(PadWith, rightPadCount);
                texts[i] = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", leftPadString, texts[i], rightPadString);
            }
            string retVal = string.Empty;
            retVal = string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, texts);
            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```